# SyntaxError on "function x.y () {...}"?

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

How can I fix the following javascript error ? This is a handler for an ASP.NET page to disable postbacks when the enter key is pressed:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function document.onkeydown() {

                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                    event.cancel = true;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Learn to use the tools available, such as jsfiddle, the web console, JSLint, etc. This problem *should* have been easily identifiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `document.onkeydown` is not a valid function name.  You probably wanted to do this:

```javascript
document.onkeydown = function(ev) {
  if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
  // ...
}
```

Or better:

```javascript
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
  if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: just as a side note... it should be `document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {` I think

Comment: You should probably add `event` argument to each of the variants.

Answer (score 1):

To add to maerics answer, to get access to the event, you need it as an argument...

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( event ) {
    console.log( event, event.keyCode );
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.cancel = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: You'd better use `e` instead of `event` in the function body.

Comment: Doh! My bad. I lost the race big time here. Thanks!